# ComboBox Value shows the end portion after Selecting an Item

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selecteditem

I have a ComboBox in my C# Winform. Some of the Item texts are larger than the size of the ComboBox. Whenever I select these values, the end portion is visible. How can I ensure that, the beginning portion is shown.

For example,

Consider the items: {"small","big text selection"}

Now, the ComboBox is large enough to show 8 characters. When I select, "big text selection",

I can only see, "election", but I would like to view "big text" instead.

Comment: Have you considered making the combo box *larger*?

Comment: that's a possibility, but I wanted to know how could I achieve what is mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it significantly to you to use `DropDownStyle` equal to `DropDown`? In this style combobox have an editor, so when yoou select new value from the list it display in the editor and cursor position set at end of text. So in this case you should send `HOME` button code to the combobox editor this will move cursor at the start of line. You can do that as shown below:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{HOME}");
    }
```

But if `DropDown` style is not significant to you just change it to `DropDownList` and you will have desired behavour.

Comment: This fulfills what I wanted achieve.

Answer (score 1):

In the `SelectedIndexChanged` event create a Timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 10;
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
timer.Start();
```

And in its Tick:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Select(0, 0);
    (sender as Timer).Stop();
    (sender as Timer).Dispose();
}
```

The `Select` call will achieve what you're after.

Comment: Wow, this is ugly. What do you need a timer for in the first place?

Comment: comboBox1.Select(0, 0), this code does not seem to serve the purpose.

Comment: @Gunner: Worked for me. Need timer because changing the text selection directly in `SelectedIndexChanged` event indeed has no effect, probably because the auto text selection (that cause the "problem" you describe) happens after that event.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at expanding the value dynamically or use a tooltip for large items..

I explained it here for how to do it for Listbox:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajoshi/archive/2010/06/15/asp-net-mvc-creating-a-single-select-list-box-and-showing-tooltip-for-lengthy-items.aspx